# Grails application is throwing NPE on Websphere 6.1

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, websphere-6.1

I have deployed my Grails 1.3.7 app to websphere 6.1.0.25. The app throws NPE

```
ERROR webapp.WebApp  - [Servlet Error]-[Filter [DeclaredResourcesPluginFilter]: filter is unavailable.]: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and it does not display the images. It seems they are related but not sure.

Things that might be related:

1- These are some of the related plugins I'm using

```
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
    runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
    compile ":lesscss-resources:1.3.0"
```

2- I have setup Websphere according to [Grails deployment document](http://grails.org/Deployment#Websphere%206.1)
meaning I have set 
"Generic JVM arguments" to "-Xverify:none" and

com.ibm.ws.classloader.getInputStream.enableIOException value: true and

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFiltersCompatibility value: true

I appreciate any suggestion on how to debug this issue.

Here: is the full stacktrace:

```
[WebContainer : 0] ERROR webapp.WebApp  - [Servlet Error]-[Filter [DeclaredResourcesPluginFilter]: filter is unavailable.]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.setContentType(SRTServletResponse.java:1141)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor635.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2395)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.setProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1129)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3315)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:483)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.processModernResource(ResourceProcessor.groovy:293)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$processModernResource.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ProcessingFilter.doFilter(ProcessingFilter.groovy:39)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:837)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:747)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:700)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:115)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:849)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3507)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1466)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
```

I added this JIRA for the Resources Plugin 
[here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-165)

Comment: I created a sample app and just added Resources plugin and it started to throw the same exception. So at this time I assume there is something from Resources Plugin that is causing it. Any idea how could be resolved?

Comment: Can you not use the resources plug-in?  I would file this as a bug with the resources plug-in folks

Comment: I wish I could just not use it but as you know a lot of other plugins depends on resources plugin. I will research a little bit more and then file a jira. Thanks

Comment: I would see if there is debug logging in the resources filter.

Comment: @chrislovecnm based on your direction, I turned on the debug flag on resource plugin and it worked. Seems the issue was related to incompatibility of WAS 6 and Grails 1.3.x. Eventually we have moved to Grails 2 and WAS 8 and things are quiet so far,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with WAS environment for versions 7.x and below.

This exception is generally seen when MIME types of the static resources are not set in WAS (`default_host`), hence you do not see the images. If you are looking for the .jpg or .png images which missing in the view then the corresponding MIME types has to be added in the server. `WAS Admin -> Environments -> Virtual Host -> default_host -> MIME Types`.

This issue is persistent in Websphere 7.x as well.

Comment: thanks for the response, I think your response is correct and reasonable, we had WAS 6 and specifically ver:6.1.0.25 had this issue there was a patch for a later version of the WAS at that time but we decided to upgrade to WAS 8, so I cannot verify your answer but it seems very reasonable. Thank you very much